# Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

```
[HttpDelete("delete")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteUserProfileAsync(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await this.userService.DeleteUserProfileAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (!result)
                {
                    return this.LmsBadRequestResult("unable to delete user profile");
                }
                else
                {
                    return this.LmsSuccessResult(message: "successfully deleted  user profile");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return this.LmsInternalServerErrorResult("failed to delete user profile");
            }
        }
```

can i pass this success message with 204 status code?
my requirement is i want to pass "successfully deleted user profile" message with 204 success result

```
        protected ObjectResult LmsSuccessResult(object result = null ,string message=null)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, result);
            }
            else
            {
                return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent,message);
            }
        }**
```

Comment: *`can i pass this success message with 204 status code?`*  Yes, you can also send a successful message with a  `404 code` , your question was not clear , what is your problem and what you want?

Comment: I want to return 204 success status code and message like "successfully deleted  user profile" @MohammadAghazadeh

Comment: 204 literally means "No Content" -- meaning a null response. You should return a 200 if you want to return content to an acceptable request. [More Info](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7231.html#status.204).